# Reading user input as a single string using QInputDialog

Tags: qt

I'm trying to use a `QInputDialog` to read user input as a single string in the format *first name: surname: employee number*

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool ok;      

QString text = QInputDialog::getText(  this,  tr("Label dialog"),  
           tr("Enter employee data as firstName:lastName:empNumber"),   
           QLineEdit::Normal, "", &ok );  
if( ok && !text.isEmpty() )  
{
    // pull apart the results here.
}
```